# Song playing during My Hero Academia Episode 53 (The Test) at the end?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

It starts around 22:00, specifically at the scene with Momo blocking the ball shots/when Mr. Aizawa is talking to Ms. Joke. It’s been played a lot in Season 3, especially in the beginning episodes, but I’m going crazy looking for the actual song and can’t find it anywhere.

Thanks :)

Also played in episode 55 here: https://youtu.be/ekyup0HPOes

Comment: I can't check the episode right now, is it [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHr94DMMCk0) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0_p3X6-qME)?

Comment: Nope, neither! It’s more slow and dramatic, with some chanting lol. Thanks though :)

Comment: Here it is again in Episode 55 https://youtu.be/ekyup0HPOes

Answer (score 0):

The song is : **Tekkin Battle**

Here is a link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_F_zfGNBBM

**Check at 1:51**